# Running Log stash In Docker Compose is throwing Error

Tags: docker-compose, logstash

I am trying to configure logstash in docker. Elastic Search is hosted in AWS EC2. I need to insert data into that using logstash. Below is the content of docker-compose.yml.

```
version:"1"
services:
     logstash:
           image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.8.0
           command: logstash -f logstash.conf
           ports:
              -"9200":9200
```

When I run "docker-compose up", it is not connecting to the AWS URL that is defined in "logstash.conf", instead it throwing below error.

```
error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}
```

Comment: This is your full `docker-compose.yml`? Your container is using the default conf, which tries to connect to another container named `elasticsearch`. You need a [`volumes`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-docker.html#load-settings-file) section linking your `logstash.conf` file to the `conf` inside your container.